# get event of a button that is dynamically added

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have this code that make user add files for attachment, and remove button to each file so my probleme is how can i get the event of the button when clicked

```
btnAttachment.setOnAction(event -> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        selectedFiles.addAll(fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(null));
        for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {
            HBox hBox = new HBox();
            hBox.getChildren().addAll(
                    new Label(selectedFile.getName() + " ( " + selectedFile.length() / 1024 + "Ko ) "),
                    new JFXButton("", new ImageView(new Image("/resources/images/minus-circle.png")))
            );
            vbAttachment.getChildren().add(hBox);
        }
        spAttachment.setVisible(true);
    });
```

and this image for more explanation

[image]

Comment: What is `JFXButton`?

Comment: it's from the library (jfoenix), i use it for desgin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a listener to the button in the usual way. I have no idea what `JFXButton` is, so this is how you would do it using a regular JavaFX `Button`:

```
for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {
    HBox hBox = new HBox();

    Button removeButton = new Button("", new ImageView(new Image("/resources/images/minus-circle.png")));
    removeButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
        vbAttachment.getChildren().remove(hBox);
        // other code you need to execute when the button is pressed...
    });

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(
            new Label(selectedFile.getName() + " ( " + selectedFile.length() / 1024 + "Ko ) "),
            removeButton
    );
    vbAttachment.getChildren().add(hBox);
}
```